# Spnego login with tomcat only works with hostname without domain name

Tags: java, tomcat, spnego

I'm working on setting up *Windows Authentication SSO* for my **Tomcat 7 server**. I'm using the `spnego sourceforge library` and after a lot of tweaking I've managed to get it to work (well, not completely).

I'm using the keytab setup and SSO works very well when I surf to my test machine using the host name without any domain suffix. As soon as I add the domain name to the URL I get a login dialog requesting credentials. If I enter those everything works as expected again, but SSO it ain't. One clue is that the krb5.conf file seems to be totally ignored.

So can anyone help me with ideas on what can be wrong? It feels like the SPN is involved, but I've tried playing around with this quite a bit and it doesn't seem to help.

Here are the information that I think is relevant.

**Setup:** 
 - AD Server is Win 2008 
 - Tomcat 7 is running on Win 8 
 - Clients are on Win 7 (Tested with IE and Chrome). 
 - Spnego lib is version 7.

**web.xml setting.**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>${catalina.home}/conf/krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>${catalina.home}/conf/login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.delegation</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**login.conf**

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    debug=true
    useTicketCache=true 
    doNotPrompt=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    isInitiator=false
    keyTab="file:///C:/test/test.keytab"
    principal=testuser;
};
```

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
   default_realm = TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
   default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
   permitted_enctypes   = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc

   [realms]
   TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL  = {
       kdc = TESTDOMAIN-KDC.testdomain.local 
       default_domain = TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   }

[domain_realm]
   .TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL = TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL 
   TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL = TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
```

Result of setspn -L testuser

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=Test Server,OU=Users,OU=Testdomain,DC=Testdomain,DC=local:
HTTP/TESTHOST
HTTP/TESTHOST.testdomain.local
```

Result of ktab -l -k test.keytab

```
Keytab name: test.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- ---------------------------------
   0 testuser@TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   0 testuser@TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   0 testuser@TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   0 testuser@TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
   0 testuser@TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL
```

DNS setting for the testhost is setup so reverse look up points to the test host with the full name.

```
ping -a 10.1.1.123
Pinging testhost.testdomain.local [10.1.1.123] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.1.1.123: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.1.1.123: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/spnego/discussion/1003769/thread/b7288dd7/ - related thread with some dialog. Just for the link to be here